# Download data the correct way from firebase to fill a listView in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, listview, google-cloud-firestore

in flutter I want to create a simple listView with some listTiles filled with data from cloud firebase. After creating the widgets and the cloud stuff my app can't start because something in the code below doesn't reach the server. I already null-checked everything because first I got many errors because of 'snapshot.data.length' and so on.

Is there anybody who knows how to download the data the correct way into the listTiles?

My code:

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Material(
    child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('jobs'),
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('jobs').snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshot) {
            if (querySnapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('error');
            }
            if (querySnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else {
              List<DocumentSnapshot> list = querySnapshot.data!.docs;
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: list.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text('${list[index].data()!}'),
                    );
                  });
            }
          },
        ))));
}
```

Heres the error-message:

```
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:34:7)
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:599:37)
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:738:21)
    <asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:558:9)
    <asynchronous suspension>
#4      starter (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:180:12)
    <asynchronous suspension>
#5      main (file:///opt/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/flutter/flutter_frontend_server/bin/starter.dart:13:24)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Thanks for your help!

Tom

Comment: Is Firebase initalized? Do you get any error messages? Are you sure `FirebaseFirestore.instance` works or maybe it should be `FirebaseStorage.instance`?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the code? It seems to be working fine when I tested it.

Comment: hi, yeah the error first appears after starting the emulator, the code itself seams to work. I edited my post with the error message. Have you already built a flutter listView with firebase after the null-statement-release? thx

Comment: @PeterKoltai were using Firebase Firestore so I think we have to use FirebaseFirestore.instance. I never used Cloud Storage till today, is there any advantage? I think its only possible if we use CloudStorage, is this correct?

Comment: I just had another Idea, is it possible to first download data (maybe in the initState() method) before the screen is build and save the data in some arrays? We used to do that in Xcode's-Swift. After downloading we eventually can use the data in the ListTiles?

Comment: @TomSchäfer Sorry, it was a mistake in my first comment, you are right, you have to use `FirebaseFirestore.instance`.

Comment: @TomSchäfer This code works perfectly for me in null-safety project. The only suggestion I have regarding code that you could declare your stream somewhere outside the `build` method so it is not executed whenever Flutter builds the UI. But it works this way as well.

Comment: @TomSchäfer I think this error is related to the Flutter build, I also have problems sometimes. Try with other iOS simulator, Android, real device etc. If it is iOS specific, try clear `pod` cache, delete `Podfile.lock`, run `pod install`.

Comment: thanks a lot @PeterKoltai, I will try to update everything. Im pretty sure its just a technical reason because it doesn't work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome, your code works, it is an issue in you build environment. I also face that sometimes, especially with iOS build.